# Can someone prove this? Difference between two exponents sum

Tags: proof-verification, summation, proof-writing, sums-of-squares

$$y^n-x^m-\int^{n}_{m}x^\phi\ln{x}\text{ d}\phi\doteq\sum^{n}_{i=1}\sum^i_{\rho=0}\left((-1)^\rho\cdot\frac{\prod\limits_{j_1=\rho+1}^{i}(j_1)}{(i-\rho)!y^\rho}y^ix^\rho\right)\frac{\prod\limits_{j_2=i+1}^{n}(j_2)}{(n-i)!x^i}x^n$$

I'm pretty sure it's correct, but I have no way of verifying/proving.

Comment: $f(\phi) = x^\phi, f'(\phi) = x^\phi \ln \phi$ so that $\int_m^n f'(\phi)d\phi = f(n)-f(m) = x^n - x^m$

Comment: And $y^n-x^n = (y-x)(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k y^{n-1-k})$